# Retrieve Dynamic Control Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Guys please help me with this..

1. I am dynamically adding 3 textboxes, 2 radiobuttons and 5 multiline textbox controls in a table **ON CLICK OF A BUTTON** in asp.net
2. I want to retrieve and store the values of each and every control.

I am very new to asp.net.  Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Are you adding controls on server side (in C# click event handler for button) or in javascript? Do you want the values on server or client side (In aspx.cs (codebehind) file or in javascript)?

Comment: how do you create the buttons ? You'll have to plug something here I guess.

Comment: access the control with the ID's given to control while creating them.

Comment: guys i have already added a button which when clicked generates the above said controls.yes i am creating the controls on click event of that button.Yes i want the values on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically adding controls to a page needs to specify an ID for each of those controls ! so when adding them you specify an ID for each of them and you can use that ID to retrieve and store data from and to those controls !

Code example on getting data from yourcontrols :

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
String name="";
String familyName="";
name=textbox1.Text.Trim();
familyName=textbox2.Text.Trim();
}
```

Comment: I am generating the controls inside a for loop and I am assigning dynamic Id's also.for example if i added three textbox dynamically id's will be textbox1,textbox2,textbox3.I am able to do this.My question How will I retrieve values from these textboxes on click of a save button. I hope you got it.

Answer (score -1):

You can always get the postback value using the `Request.Form[]`

For example

```
Request.Form[Control.UniqueID]
```

To work this correct you need to give the "unique name id" of your controls (not the id name)

In the request.form lives all the post parameters from the page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(VS.90).aspx